# Zend Framework menu translation

Tags: php, zend-framework, navigation

I am developing an multilingual web application.I have menu elemnts which came from xml file but i dont know how to translate menu.On the other hand,I could translate normal content of site in the view like this:

```
<?=$this->translate->_('Members Login')
```

My bootstrap file:

```
    class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    private $_acl = null;
    private $_auth = null;

    protected function _initAutoLoad()
    {
        $modelLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => '',
        'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH
        ));
        if (Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()) {
            Zend_Registry::set('role', Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->read()->role);
        } else {
            Zend_Registry::set('role', 'guest');
        }
        $this->_acl = new Model_LibraryAcl();
        $this->_auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

        $fc = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $fc->registerPlugin(new Plugin_AccessCheck($this->_acl, $this->_auth));
        return $modelLoader;
    }

    function _initViewHelpers()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('layout');
        $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
        $view = $layout->getView();

        $view->doctype('HTML4_STRICT');
        $view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-type','text/html;charset=UTF-8')
                         ->appendName('description','The Best Freelance Projects');

        $view->headTitle('Freelance Duty');

        $navContainerConfig = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH.'/configs/navigation.xml','nav');
        $navContainer = new Zend_Navigation($navContainerConfig);
        $view->navigation($navContainer)
              ->setAcl($this->_acl)
              ->setRole(($this->_auth->getStorage()->read())?$this->_auth->getStorage()->read()->role:'guest')
              ->findAllBy('class', 'nav_header');
    }

    function _initSetTranslations()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('layout');
        $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
        $view = $layout->getView();

        $translate = new Zend_Translate('gettext',APPLICATION_PATH.'/languages/tr.mo','tr');
        $translate->setLocale('tr');
        $view->translate = $translate;
        Zend_Registry::set('TranslationObject', $translate);
    }

}
```

and write the menu in view like this:

```
echo $this->navigation()->menu()->setUlClass('nav_header');
```

i dont know howto translate menu
Any comments?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Titles and labels could be translated automatically, when you use `Zend_Navigation`. Check out [reference guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.navigation). Just pick your helper and set `Zend_Translate` to it.

**EDIT**: First of all, in code from comment you're doing two things wrong:
1. Using `setUseTranslator` and passing translator object into it. But `setUseTranslator` takes boolean value describing to use or not translator. You set translator using `setTranslator` method:

```
$view->navigation($navContainer) 
     //RB setUseTranslator is unnecessary, because it's true by deafult
     ->setTranslator(Zend_Registry::get('TranslationObject'));
```

2. Before use chaining be sure, that method returns object that you want:

```
$view->navigation($navContainer)
     ->setAcl($this->_acl)
     ->setRole(($this->_auth->getStorage()->read())?$this->_auth->getStorage()->read()->role:'guest')
     ->findAllBy('class', 'nav_header'); //that returns an array, not Zend_Navigation object!
```

So you can't do:

```
$navigation->findAllBy('class', 'nav_header') 
           ->setUseTranslator(Zend_Registry::get('TranslationObject')); //wrong methid here, should be setTranslator, as mentioned above
```

Call `setTranslator` on `$navigation` object and it should work.

Comment: Hi @singles,I have used setUseTranslator in my bootstrap file like this:`code`$view->navigation($navContainer)
        ->setAcl($this->_acl)
      ->setRole(($this->_auth->getStorage()->read())?$this->_auth->getStorage()->read()->role:'guest')
        ->findAllBy('class', 'nav_header')
        ->setUseTranslator(Zend_Registry::get('TranslationObject'));         The TranslationObject is for my XML language content file.I keep it in registry inorder to use it

Comment: Please, reformat that code or better edit question. And you didn't write does it worked ;)

Comment: Thanks @single,I have followed your instruction and it works now:)

Answer (score 0):

Zend_Translate should help. Take a look here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.html

Comment: As i wrote in my bootstrap file i have alrady used zend_translate.The problem is about menu translation.Because,menu content isn't constant value, it dynamically comes from xml

Comment: It's not important, that menu items came from XML. You passing PARSED file into constructor `Zend_Navigation`, so it should be able to fetch menu labels and translate them.